# Recursively deleting a BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a BST and want to clip the tree once a certain depth is met. I'm running into a `NullPointerException` when attempting to traverse the tree, setting the nodes past the depth wanted to null.

Is my logic right with what I'm doing here? It seems like a pretty straightforward problem but I can't seem to understand what's causing this error.

```
public void clip(int d) {
    int counter = 0;
    clip_helper(d, root, counter);
}

public void clip_helper(int depth, Node n, int c) {

    if (n != null) {
        c++;
        if (c == depth) {
            n.left = null;
            n.right = null;
        }
    }
    clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
    clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
}
```

*Should also add that I'm fairly new to recursive solutions, so I might be missing something blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
```

These lines are causing the NullPointer Exception as your program never ends
Even if Node n is null, It still goes to the left and the right which is causing this

To solve this, Just add a null check condition on top of your code

```
if(n==null)
   return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change :

```
clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
```

to :

```
if(n.left!=null && n.right!=null) {
    clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
    clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
}
```

or :

```
if(c==depth) {
    clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
    clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
}
```

because the recursive call of clip_helper won't stop.

Answer (score 1):

You should return if Node is null as below

```
public void clip(int d) {
    int counter = 0;
    clip_helper(d, root, counter);
}

public void clip_helper(int depth, Node n, int c) {
    if(n== null ) return;
    if (n != null) {
        c++;
        if (c == depth) {
            n.left = null;
            n.right = null;
        }
    }
    clip_helper(depth, n.left, c);
    clip_helper(depth, n.right, c);
}
```